# Python Regex Parsing from OCR result

Tags: python, regex, text-parsing

I am trying to parse the following text

Input:

```
value1 @ M Temperature       1.30 ohmm       @ 74 00 degF  
value2 Q M. Temperature          1 70 ohmm @ 74.00 degF   
value3 @ m Temperature       110 ohmm        @ 74.00 degF
```

Expected Output:

```
value1 = 1.30  
value1 temp = 74.00 degF
```

etc

I was able to extract the text from the file but having issues making the variances in the OCR output dynamically parseable. So when it appears as 'Temp' it still pulls the expected value among other things.

```
import re

with open('C:\Users\NthDS1\Documents\samp.txt', 'r') as f:
    data  = list()
    group = dict()
    for key, value in re.findall(r'(.*)Temperature\s*([\dE+-.]+)', f.read()):
        if key in group:
            data.append(group)
            group = dict()
        group[key] = value
    data.append(group)

print data
```

Comment: Are you interested in the `1.30` (a resistance value) and are these the only variations (space in favour of a dot) ? If so you could use https://regex101.com/r/tt3TgM/1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
data = [dict(zip(['name', 'ohmm', 'degF'], re.findall('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[\d\.]+(?=\sohmm)|[\d\.]+(?=\sdegF$)', i.strip('\n'))) for i in open('filename.txt')]
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'value1', 'ohmm': '1.30', 'degF': '00'}, {'name': 'value2', 'ohmm': '70', 'degF': '74.00'}, {'name': 'value3', 'ohmm': '110', 'degF': '74.00'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, this output appears to be what I need but I'm receiving syntax errors when I try to build, at the end bracket.

Comment: I thought it was a python issue, but I cant determine what the syntax error is. I think it's in shaping the array but I cant trace it back

Comment: I figured out the syntax but this only yields the names; [{'name': 'SPECTRAL'}, {'name': 'DUAL'},

Comment: @FanScience Can you post the data you are currently using? `SPECTRAL` and `DUAL` do not occur in the data posted.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only variance (space for dot), you could try

```
\b(?P<value>\d+(?:[. ]\d+)?)\b\s*
(?P<unit>\w+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tt3TgM/1/).

---

With the help of a little function, you could use

```
import re

data = """
value1 @ M Temperature       1.30 ohmm       @ 74 00 degF  
value2 Q M. Temperature          1 70 ohmm @ 74.00 degF   
value3 @ m Temperature       110 ohmm        @ 74.00 degF 
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
    \b(?P<value>\d+(?:[. ]\d+)?)\b\s*
    (?P<unit>\w+)''', re.X)

def afterwork(match):
    value = match.replace(' ', '.')
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return value

values = [(afterwork(m.group('value')), m.group('unit')) 
          for m in rx.finditer(data)]
print(values)
```

Yielding

```
[(1.3, 'ohmm'), (74.0, 'degF'), (1.7, 'ohmm'), (74.0, 'degF'), (110.0, 'ohmm'), (74.0, 'degF')]
```

Comment: @FanScience: If it works for you, consider accepting / upovting the answer (green tick on the left).